# How to submit locale-aware values in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

I wish to enter a double via a Struts 2 textfield, but respecting the current locale. Example: for "en" it would be entered as "3.4" (using a point), in "de" it would be entered as "3,4" (using a comma).

In my app, the locale is set via the request_locale parameter e.g.:

```
<s:url id="localeDE" namespace="/" action="locale" >
<s:param name="request_locale" >de</s:param>
</s:url>
```

and the number format "format.number" is defined in the en and de properties file as

```
format.number ={0,number,#0.0##}
```

But I cannot get it to work. I've tried using the following to input the number:

```
<s:textfield key="global.amount" name="%{getFormatted('format.number','myValue')}" />
```

This doesn't work - the submit doesn't fail, but the value is not assigned to the target action (it remains the default 0,0), and the warning "Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored" is written to the logs.

I've also tried this:

```
<s:textfield key="global.amount" name="%{getText('format.number',{myValue})}" />
```

This doesn't work - the submit doesn't fail, but the value is not assigned to the target action (it remains the default 0,0), and the warning "Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored" is written to the logs.

And tried this:

```
<s:textfield key="global.amount" name="myValue" />
```

The submit fails, the input page is re-displayed, and the following is written to the browser (of course because 3.4 is expected, not 3,4):

```
Invalid field value for field "myValue"
The following is written to the logs:
Apr 03, 2015 9:58:18 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
Avertissement: Error setting expression 'myValue' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@8a9396'
ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setMyValue" failed for object com.planet.user.action.FinanceData@326ce2 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.planet.user.action.FinanceData.setMyValue([Ljava.lang.String;)]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1285)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1474)
```

*Displaying* a value in the current locale is easy, using:

```
<s:textfield key="global.amount" value="%{getText('format.number',{myValue})}" />
```

But how can we allow the value to be *submitted* locale-aware?

I couldn't find any example/thread regarding this. The only hint I found was the following in the struts doc: 
"... type conversion is locale aware. The solution is to again use the message formats as defined above, by using the getText Method of ActionSupport"

(see [formatting-dates-and-numbers](https://struts.apache.org/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html) )

This suggests that locale-aware submission is possible out-of-the-box with Struts, but how? Any help much appreciated ...

Comment: You should learn Struts 2 basics, it has nothing with localization but you should read the link posted by you carefully. It has code examples that you can try on your own. If you have a concrete question you can ask it, but this question can't help future readers because in its current state as is written.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback RomanC. Surely you are right that I am missing something basic here. Before posting I did try (a lot) to figure out how the info on that page can help, and also scoured several books ... but I found no info on how to submit data in a locale-sensitive fashion. Please can you explain why its not to do with localization? A user should be able to enter values according to their locale ...

Comment: Localization and i18n is a addhoc  topic in Struts framework and a neat feature used by developers for years. Before using it make sure all other parts are working properly. The documentation is written for developers who already know how Struts2 works and a problem you have is not related to i18n.

Comment: Thanks RomanC. All other parts are working fine - I have a very simple Struts2 example with a form which just submits one value from a textfield to an Action's (extends ActionSupport) Java type double property. I guess what I need to understand is, can the i18n be used to reverse-format the value back to the format expected by the double converter? Or, do I need to implement the reverse-formatting myself (in custom interceptor or in action setter)? Or do I need to implement my own converter? How is this normally done?

Comment: @RomanC - I've solved the problem now, my answer is below. There seems to be a bug with the double primitive converter, which explains why even the simplest example wasn't working (and hence wondering if some other mechanism needed to be used e.g. i18n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:
Struts automatically handles the conversion of the localized data input, so there is no need to apply formatting to the textfield tag as I tried in my question. However, there appears to be a bug when using primitive double when submitting non-en localized data input ... hence my simple form submission was not working and so I thought I had to apply formatting.

The "solution" is to use Double instead of primitive double, although I'm not sure if this more of a workaround to a possible bug in Struts rather than a solution.

For example, here is my action:

```
public class FinanceData extends ActionSupport {

    private double myValue;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

Here is my struts form:

```
<s:form action="saveData" namespace="/user">

    <s:textfield key="global.amount" name="myValue"/>
    <s:submit/>

</s:form>
```

And here is my struts.xml:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="user" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">
       <action name="saveData" class="com.planet.user.action.FinanceData">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/dataSummary.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
       </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

With this, when submitting a value of "3,4" in the German session locale, the submit fails with the message:
Invalid field value for field "myValue".

If the primitive double is changed to Double in the Action class, the submit works fine and the "3,4" is correctly written to the Double property (obviously becomes "3.4").

Whilst troubleshooting I seem to remember seeing some issues in struts with the double converter, but I can't find the details any more.

Struts version used: 2.3.20, browser Chrome.